# How to generate random numbers from a given range with provided distribution probability

Tags: shell, random

Suppose I have a list of files and given probability (larger number indicates higher probability)

- fileA (8)
- fileB (1)
- fileC (3)
- fileD (4)
- ...

How can I generate a random sequence to simulate the relative probability, just like `shuf` tool does.

The length of the sequence might be shorter than the number of file set. This should be part of the input to a shell function, so any lightweight solution (using traditional Unix tools) would be preferred, while make use of heavy libraries or platforms (like Matlab) is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a file randomly with relative probabilities given by:

```
$ cat file
fileA (8)
fileB (1)
fileC (3)
fileD (4)
```

Use this:

```
$ awk -F'[ ()]' '{for (i=1;i<=$(NF-1);i++) print $1}' file |shuf | head -n1
fileD
```

Comment: Looks nice by converting the problem into ordinary shuffle!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 $ awk -v n=10 '{k=a[NR-1]+$2; a[NR]=k; v[k]=$1}
             END{srand();
                 for(j=1;j<=n;j++) 
                    {r=int(rand()*a[NR])+1; 
                     for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) 
                         if(r<=a[i])  {print v[a[i]]; break}}}' weights


$ cat weights
fileA 8
fileB 1
fileC 3
fileD 4
```

usage, creates 10 random samples based on relative weights

```
$ awk -v n=10 '...' weights
fileA
fileA
fileA
fileA
fileA
fileA
fileA
fileD
fileD
fileA
```